# How to parse triple stashed tags in handlebarsjs using Python parse

Tags: python, parsing, handlebars.js

**Background**

I am using the handlebars templating language to create documents. In order to create the JSON-file to populate a certain handlebars file with values, I want to extract all handlebars expressions in that file, using a Python script. The Python parse module seems right for the job, since it has a findall function, which finds all occurrences of a certain pattern.

**Problem**

Parse uses braces to enclose the pattern to be searched for, e.g.

```
parse("One {} three", "One two three")
```

yields

```
<Result ('two',) {}>
```

However, the patterns I am looking for are tripple stashed like so

```
{{{<some expression>}}}
```

which would force me to escape the braces. I tried using backslash, i.e.

```
parse("One \{\{\{{}\}\}\} three", "One {{{some_number}}} three")
```

in order to extract

```
some_number
```

but this does not work. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is probably not too useful, but I have a terrible hack that you might be able to use. I discovered one day that I could do a kind of partial application (typically inside a for-loop) by calling `format` on strings with nested braces. Here's an example:

```
In [1]: url = "http://{hostname}:{{port}}/{{{resource}}}"

In [2]: url.format(hostname="localhost", resource="new_var_name")
Out[2]: 'http://localhost:{port}/{new_var_name}'
```

The triple braces have a set of escaped braces inside them whereas the double braces just get the outer set peeled away. I never used triple braces because why would you want to rename your variable unless you were doing some dirty dynamic programming stuff, but I digress...

Anyway, this gets real bizarre when you go to four braces (but I usually just keep it at ones and twos):

```
In [3]: url = "http://{hostname}:{{port}}/{{{endpoint}}}/{{{{resource}}}}"

In [4]: url.format(hostname="localhost", endpoint="wut").format(port=1, wut="hey")
Out[4]: 'http://localhost:1/hey/{resource}'

In [5]: url.format(hostname="localhost", endpoint="wut").format(port=1, wut="hey").format(
    ...: resource="thatsright")
Out[5]: 'http://localhost:1/hey/thatsright'
```

Anyway, it occurs to me that if you could drop the 3-braces down to twos, then you'd probably be in business and get what you need by just calling `format` on the whole resulting string (no idea how performant that would be).

I used this hack to write some dirty code that you had to squint real hard at to understand what it was doing because it was a string that was like `{}{}{{}}{{}}` and then I'd interpolate the singles and save the latter ones for passes inside a for-loop. I felt guilty about that code. I still do, but I also still feel good about stumbling upon the technique.